# Compute the remainder of $2^{(2^{17})}+1$ when divided by $19$

Tags: ring-theory

Compute the remainder of $2^{2^{17}}+1$ when divided by $19$

Hint given in book: Computer the remainder of $2^{17}$ modulo $18$

My attempt:

From Fermat's little theorem, $2^{18}=1(mod19)$

I have done sums where I express the number given as this $LHS ^{something} \times something$ but I can't seem to be able to do that here!

I don't understand how to relate this to what I have to find or how to use the hint given. Please help!

Comment: using the given hint, what did you get for  $2^{17} \pmod{18}$ ?

Comment: I didn't use the hint because I didn't find it relevant, but if I have to use it, I don't know how to find $2^{17}(mod 18)$ because $18$ is not prime, and I only know results for Primes...

Comment: Okay, the basic idea is to write the exponent term as $18k+l$ and appeal to Fermat's little theorem

Comment: Since the exponent term is $2^{17}$ here, you want to work $2^{17} \pmod{18}$ and you're right 18 is not prime, so it won't evaluate to $1$ - you may reduce it manually however...

Comment: to calculate $2^{17}(mod18)$ you can do like this , first $2^4=-2(mod18)$ then raise power $4$ both sides i.e $2^{16}=(-2)^4=16(mod18)$ now multiply 2 both side $2^{17}=32(mod18)=14(mod18)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as I commented $2^{17}=14(mod18)$ i.e $2^{17}=14+18k$ for some $k\in \Bbb{N}$ then $$2^{2^{17}}=2^{14+18k}=2^{14}\cdot2^{{18}k}$$ and since $2^{18}=1(mod19)$ thus$2^{18k}=1(mod19)$ therefore $$2^{2^{17}}=2^{14}(mod19)$$
Now can you end from here?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've been trying to figure out what happens when I add 1, but with no luck.

Comment: you're left to calculate $2^{14}(mod19)$ so again approach this as I did for $2^{17}(mod(18)$ , notice that $2^{5}=-6(mod19)$ implying $2^{10}=(-6)^2(mod19)=17(mod19)$ thus $2^{14}=2^4\cdot2^{10}=16\cdot17(mod19)=272(mod19)=6(mod19)$